# What does declaring a bash array with -A do?

Tags: bash, shell-script, array, associative-array

In Example_1, when i have declared `city` to be an array with `declare -A`, why is `Bangalore` output first when the array is printed in the `for` loop?

```
Bangalore
Remote
Kolkata
Ahmedabad
Hyderabad
Pune
Mumbai
Delhi
Chennai
```

in Example_2, I believe its sorted in numerical order

## example_1

```
$ cat novice_3.sh 
#!/bin/bash/
declare -A  city=(  ["0"]="Mumbai" ["8"]="Delhi" ["16"]="Kolkata"
                    ["26"]="Bangalore" ["32"]="Chennai"  ["40"]="Pune" 
                    ["50"]="Hyderabad" ["56"]="Ahmedabad"  ["17"]="Remote" )
for i in ${!city[@]};do
echo "${city[$i]}"
done

$ sh novice_3.sh
Bangalore
Remote
Kolkata
Ahmedabad
Hyderabad
Pune
Mumbai
Delhi
Chennai
```

## example_2

```
$ cat novice_3.sh
#!/bin/bash/
declare   city=( ["0"]="Mumbai" ["8"]="Delhi" ["16"]="Kolkata"
                 ["26"]="Bangalore" ["32"]="Chennai"  ["40"]="Pune" 
                 ["50"]="Hyderabad" ["56"]="Ahmedabad"  ["17"]="Remote" )
for i in ${!city[@]};do
echo "${city[$i]}"
done

$ sh novice_3.sh
Mumbai
Delhi
Kolkata
Remote
Bangalore
Chennai
Pune
Hyderabad
Ahmedabad
```

Answer (score 4):

In bash, arrays can be either **indexed** or **associative**.  Indexed arrays have a numeric index, and are (by default) iterated through by the numeric order of their indices.

An associative array (also known as a `hash` or `hashed array`) in bash can use any string as the index (aka `key`) - this string can be numeric (or appear to be numeric, there's little difference in a bash script), or it can be any other valid string.

Associative arrays in bash are, as they are in many languages, unordered.  If you just iterate through the array (e.g. without sorting the keys), you will get the array elements in a semi-random order.

Arrays in bash are, by default, indexed arrays.  You can explicitly declare an indexed array with `declare -a` (with a lowercase `a`.  Whether `declare`d to be indexed, or created as an indexed array by default, if you try to set an array element with a non-numeric index, the index will always evaluate to `0`, override or creating the value (if any) of the zeroth element of the array.

e.g.

```
$ declare -a foo
$ foo[0]=5
$ foo[1]=2
$ declare -p foo
declare -a foo=([0]="5" [1]="2")
```

OK, that's what you'd expect.  But now try setting `foo[bar]`:

```
$ foo[bar]=99
$ declare -p foo
declare -a foo=([0]="99" [1]="2")
```

Similarly, you can declare an array to be associative with `declare -A` (note the **capital** `A`).  This will force the array to be associative even if ALL of the indices are numeric.

```
$ unset foo
$ declare -A foo
$ foo[0]=5
$ foo[1]=2
$ foo[bar]=99
$ declare -p foo
declare -A foo=([bar]="99" [0]="5" [1]="2" )
```

So, the answer to your question is that in example_1, you declared `city` to be an **associative** array.  In example_2, you didn't, so it is, by default, an **indexed** array.